# XSLT ignores template for child element

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes

I am trying to transform HTML to XML using XSLT:

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p class="one">Some paragraph 1.</p>
    <p class="one">Some paragraph 2.</p>
    <p class="one">Some paragraph 3  with <em>em</em>.</p>
    <p class="one">Some paragraph 4.</p>
    <p class="one">Some paragraph 5.</p>
    <h3>Some heading</h3>
    <p class="two">Some other paragraph 1 with <em>em</em>.</p>
    <p class="two">Some other paragraph 2.</p>
    <p class="two">Some other paragraph 3.</p>
    <p class="two">Some other paragraph 4.</p>
    <p class="two">Some other paragraph 5.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Desired output:

```
Some paragraph 1.
Some paragraph 2.
Some paragraph 3  with <emphasis>em</emphasis>.
Some paragraph 4.
Some paragraph 5.
Some heading
<paragraph>Some other paragraph 1 with <emphasis>em</emphasis>.</paragraph>
<paragraph>Some other paragraph 2.</paragraph>
<paragraph>Some other paragraph 3.</paragraph>
<paragraph>Some other paragraph 4.</paragraph>
<paragraph>Some other paragraph 5.</paragraph>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:output indent="yes" />


<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="html/body" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="em">
    <emphasis><xsl:value-of select="."/></emphasis>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="p[@class='two']">
    <paragraph><xsl:value-of select="."/></paragraph>
</xsl:template>
```

Output of this XSLT tranformation:

```
Some paragraph 1.
Some paragraph 2.
Some paragraph 3  with <emphasis>em</emphasis>.
Some paragraph 4.
Some paragraph 5.
Some heading
<paragraph>Some other paragraph 1 with em.</paragraph>
<paragraph>Some other paragraph 2.</paragraph>
<paragraph>Some other paragraph 3.</paragraph>
<paragraph>Some other paragraph 4.</paragraph>
<paragraph>Some other paragraph 5.</paragraph>
```

Template for `em` element seems to work fine when no other template is defined for parent element (`p.one`). However, when there is template for parent element (`p.two`), template for child (`em`) element seems to get ignored by tranformation and instead of getting:

```
<paragraph>Some other paragraph 1 with <emphasis>em</emphasis>.</paragraph>
```

I get:

```
<paragraph>Some other paragraph 1 with em.</paragraph>
```

Why is XSLT ignoring template for `em` element in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's getting ignored because you are simply printing out the value with:

```
<paragraph><xsl:value-of select="."/></paragraph>
```

If you want the `em` template to be applied on the contents of the `p[@class='two']` template, then you should replace it with:

```
<xsl:template match="p[@class='two']">
    <paragraph><xsl:apply-templates /></paragraph>
</xsl:template>
```

Now the contents of `<paragraph>` will be processed in a template if there is one (not simply converted into text and printed out).

Comment: Thanks, that works. Since em elements are used inside lot of other elements, is there any way to make ``em`` template work without using apply-templates within every other template?

Comment: If a template doesn't call any other template, the template processing ends there. You can use, of course, generic templates (with `match="*"`) if you have very similar situations. You can also choose which templates to process using `<xsl:apply-templates select="..." />`